# Jenkins fails to compile Maven for my Selenium Project

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, apache-poi

I am trying to schedule my project on Maven. It uses Apache POI. Project works fine on my Laptop but it fails to compile Maven on Jenkins that is on a remote machine in our office. The error I face is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile** (default-testCompile) on project GunAV-test-automation: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/Mytest/-42/src/test/java/utilities/ReadExcel.java:[11,37] **package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist**

[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/Mytest/-42/src/test/java/utilities/ReadExcel.java:[12,37] package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist**

[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

How could I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have an `org.apache.poi` dependency in the POM file?

Comment: yes it looks like:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix a compilation error

```
package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist
```

you should add a [poi-ooxml](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml) maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency contains [org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/package-summary.html) package.